# Send an email setup as a file

Tags: email, pop3

Is it possible to send a file that would contain settings for a phone to set up an email account such as set up a POP3 account on a phone. 
So I could send it to a user on the network and then they just have to enter their credentials for that email account.
I have tried looking but mostly I've found people who cannot connect to their mail account.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a text file that contains the relevant server details, and username and password, with instructions, but there is no file extension, which when clicked, automatically creates an email account.